# Making tabs with only CSS2

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a tabbed interface so that there is no line underneath the selected tab, regardless of the font size of the text inside the tab, and using only CSS2. I added a bottom border but am not sure how to remove the bottom border underneath the selected tab. If I try a negative margin it simply adds a space between the bottom border and the tabs. I could try using an image to create the bottom border instead of using the bottom-border CSS feature; however, I'm trying to avoid this. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/yet5uehy/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#1"><span>Tab1</span></a></li>
            <li id="selected"><a href="#2"><span>Tab2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#3"><span>Tab3</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    /* Centers and adjusts length of the line that is
     separating the tabs from the rest of the page */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 98%;

}

#tabs {
    float: left;
    width:100%;
    font: 12px Arial;

    /* Adds line separating tabs from rest of page */
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #cccccc;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

#tabs ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;

    /* Adds padding on sides of the entire tabbed bar */
    padding:5px 5px;
}

#tabs ul li {
    float:left;

    background-image: url('righttab.jpg');
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;

    /* Adds space between each tab */
    margin:0px 3px;
    padding:0;
}

#tabs ul li a {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;

    background-image: url('lefttab.jpg');
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;

    /* Adds padding on sides of hyperlink area 
     to reveal curved edges of tab */
    padding:0px 3px;
    margin:0px;
}

#tabs ul li a span {
    float: left;

    background-image: url('midtab.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center top;

    /* Adds padding between the tab text
      and the edges of the tab */
    padding:3px 5px;
    margin:0px;
}


/* Formatting for selected tab */
#tabs li#selected {
    background-image: url('right-selected.jpg');
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}

#tabs li#selected a {
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;

    background-image: url('left-selected.jpg');
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
}

#tabs li#selected a span {
    background-image: url('mid-selected.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center top;

}
```

Comment: You could combine a negative bottom margin with a bottom border of the same color as the bottom pixel of your selected tab images, but that depends on what the images look like. I'm assuming that if you want to remove the border the tab background will blend with the page background.

Comment: first i didn't understand it correctly now i understood

Comment: there are many solutions for this one of the one is this http://jsfiddle.net/6dhdcLm1/1/

Comment: but the question needs to be proper with the background image for selected and unselected tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/th8bucda/

I modified the end of your css for the selected item:

```
#tabs li#selected a {
    display:block;
    font-weight: bold;

    background-image: url('http://s10.postimg.org/kberhjcr9/left_selected.gif');
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;

    **border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    margin-bottom:-5px;**
```

Comment: You could use 1 px I think, I just put 5px to test easy.

Answer (score -1):

I created a fiddle with what I guess can help you in the right direction. Because I have no clue how your images look like, this fiddle is **without** images.

The only modified CSS is:

```
#tabs li#selected {
    background-image: url('right-selected.jpg');
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    /* added: */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height:21px; // one pixel more then original tab
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-1px;
    top:1px; // position tab over bottom border
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hf5th1wz/